# What kind of food should be stored in a refrigerator's "snack pan" drawer?

Tags: equipment, food-safety, storage-method, refrigerator

(This may be a silly question, but I'll ask anyway since I *am* curious about this.)

We have an older fridge and it has a drawer labeled **"snack pan."**  I'm not sure how to understand "snack" here.

- *What* is a snack pan refrigerator drawer intended to hold? Is it primarily for deli meats? Or else should deli meats go in the "chilled meat compartment"?  What else goes in a snack pan?
- Is the benefit of a snack pan drawer to simply provide a place for smaller/shorter items to keep the shelves free for other things, or does food *being* in snack pan affect the food differently (such as how the chilled meat compartment is colder?)

I tried searching Google already, but all I ended up with were pages of replacement parts, repair instructions, and a few spammy links. Sadly, there was nothing truly informative.  So here I am.

Comment: I assume you either don't have the manual or its not useful. Could you post a picture?

Comment: Suggest you stick a refrigerator thermometer in there.  If it is radically different from the main refrigerator temperature you will know; if it is not, you can just use it for convenience.

Comment: Humidity varies too, so even if it's the same temperature, it might not be as good for vegetables if it's more open. That said, I wouldn't be surprised if it's not much different from the rest of the fridge, though, and is just a gimmick/convenience for small stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that "snack drawers" tend to be the same temperature as the rest of the refrigerator and really just exist as a place for you to corral small items/kid-friendly foods. I know some people that put pudding, cheese sticks, etc. in their snack drawer without issue.